# Chainlink job returning previous pipelines to external initiator after bridge call

Tags: chainlink

I have a job in my chainlink node that is described as follows:

```
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "essevai2"
externalJobID = "xxxxxxx"
observationSource = """
    parse_request  [type="jsonparse" path="address" data="$(jobRun.requestBody)"]
    send_to_bridge [type="bridge" name="getidentityfromaddress" requestData="{ \\"id\\": 0, \\"data\\": {\\"address\\": $(parse_request) }}"]

    parse_request -> send_to_bridge
"""
```

And the bridge is set correctly as I can see the return and the job completing successfully;

I've also set an external initiator for this job that can trigger it successfully

If I delete all my jobs and all my runs and create a new job with identical spec, it returns correctly the pipeline to my CURL call;

Although the problem lies when I call this job for the second or more consecutive time,
as an example, this is the response that this job run returned for the **jobId 26**, note on the json body that this is the pipeline with id 16.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "pipelineRun",
        "id": "16",
        "attributes": {
            "outputs": [
                "{\"jobRunID\":0,\"data\":{\"ethereum_address\":\"redacted\",\"country_code\":\"ZWE\",\"result\":\"ZWE\"},\"result\":\"ZWE\",\"statusCode\":200}"
            ],
            "errors": [
                null
            ],
            "inputs": {
                "jobRun": {
                    "meta": null,
                    "requestBody": "{\n        \"address\": \"redacted\"\n}"
                },
                "jobSpec": {
                    "databaseID": 11,
                    "externalJobID": "e4942a02-8a8b-4bf3-8a2f-05fe68d4a51f",
                    "name": "essevai2"
                },
                "parse_request": "redacted",
                "send_to_bridge": "{\"jobRunID\":0,\"data\":{\"ethereum_address\":\"redacted\",\"country_code\":\"ZWE\",\"result\":\"ZWE\"},\"result\":\"ZWE\",\"statusCode\":200}"
            },
            "taskRuns": [
                {
                    "type": "jsonparse",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.443875Z",
                    "finishedAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.443927Z",
                    "output": "\"redacted\"",
                    "error": null,
                    "dotId": "parse_request"
                },
                {
                    "type": "bridge",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.443968Z",
                    "finishedAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.476507Z",
                    "output": "\"{\\\"jobRunID\\\":0,\\\"data\\\":{\\\"ethereum_address\\\":\\\"redacted\\\",\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"ZWE\\\",\\\"result\\\":\\\"ZWE\\\"},\\\"result\\\":\\\"ZWE\\\",\\\"statusCode\\\":200}\"",
                    "error": null,
                    "dotId": "send_to_bridge"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.443251Z",
            "finishedAt": "2021-11-01T00:39:49.476523Z",
            "pipelineSpec": {
                "id": 11,
                "jobID": 0,
                "dotDagSource": "    parse_request  [type=\"jsonparse\" path=\"address\" data=\"$(jobRun.requestBody)\"]\n    send_to_bridge [type=\"bridge\" name=\"getidentityfromaddress\" requestData=\"{ \\\"id\\\": 0, \\\"data\\\": {\\\"address\\\": $(parse_request) }}\"]\n\n    parse_request -> send_to_bridge\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that the chainlink node will return the correct/current job pipeline or the bridge output to my external initiator that did the request?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps this is an issue worthy to add to the chainlink github?

Comment: Hi @PatrickCollins, great tutorials btw; I believe that the underlying problem of not sending the correct jobId is indeed a issue worth mentioning, although I've realized that jobs are asynchronous by nature and took a different approach of not depending on the node returning the correct jobId. Note for anyone stumbling in the same problems...